# Twitter - tweets of his followers displaying by providing oauth_token and oauth_token_secret

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

In our student portal , after student signs into the system we want to display his twitter accounts feeds ( whatever the tweets he gets when he signs into his twitter account,all his follower tweets  ) in addition to the other system functionality

I was not knowing any thing about twitter and never used it . I created account two days ago and through some applications I got **oauth_token_secret**  and **oauth_token** of the created account .

Do we have any java script or Jquery that takes **oauth_token_secret**  and **oauth_token** that displays all his follower tweets ?  At this level we are OK in providing straight forward plain **oauth_token_secret**  or **oauth_token**  or direct **username** and **password**

I looked at the widgets mentioned at http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets . But they are only to display on public sites and they don't display user follower tweets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at the API call [home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline) to get this working.  There are a few [JS libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#javascript) which will handle Twitter OAuth for you, although it would be wise to handle this via your app itself. Roughly speaking, you need to:

- Read up on [Twitter's use of OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth).
- [Register an application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) with Twitter.
- Implement a system for authorizing your users, and storing their OAuth data.
- Call `home_timeline` to get the data you want.

The details of how all of this works will depend on your server framework, etc. It's not that hard if you can use one of the many 3rd-party libraries out there that handle this work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hints and I will check them